# Kotlin - Type mismatch. Required: Context Found: String

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to detect the sim cards and changes from my application not changing from sim card manager of the phone. so my code shows error (Type mismatch. Required: Context Found: String) in (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) and i don't know the problem.

how can i resolve it?

I know that there is similar subject in the stack overflow platform, but i need help at this subject

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.core.content.ContentProviderCompat.requireContext
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.gabiley.emoney.DataStore.StoreAccountNum
import com.gabiley.emoney.ViewModelClass.MyViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService

Button(onClick = {
  val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
  val simCount = telephonyManager.phoneCount

  val simOptions: List<String> = (0 until simCount).map {index ->
     telephonyManager.simOperatorName
  }
}) {
    Text(text = "get data")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the getSystemService from context. Try the below code.

```
val context = LocalContext.current
Button(onClick = {
    val telephonyManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val simCount = telephonyManager.phoneCount
    val simOptions: List<String> = (0 until simCount).map { index ->
        telephonyManager.simOperatorName
    }
}) {
    Text(text = "get data")
}
```

Remember, getPhoneCount from TelephonyManger is deprecated now. Use  getActiveModemCount instead.